# phpQuery: не работает манипуляция с объектами в файле

Tags: php, phpquery

Проблема: не работает манипуляция с объектами средствами бибилиотеки `phpQuery` в уже созданном php-файле. Моя задача - менять содержимое уже созданного php-файла с html-разметкой.

```
$doc = phpQuery::newDocumentFile("../".$filename); // здесь всё работает; у меня это файл test.php
$title = $doc['title']; // Здесь всё нормально; выводил через echo $title->text();
$title->text("content"); // Не работает
$doc->find('#test')->append('some content'); // Не работает
```

Последняя строка в точности из [готовых примеров](http://codingexplained.com/coding/php/manipulating-dom-documents-with-phpquery), разве что ID поменял на свой. Видимо, я упустил какие-то ограничения библиотеки на возможности работы с файлами. Если это так, то какие именно?

---

**Обновление**

Добавлю [MWE-исходники](https://yadi.sk/d/XSIVaPmYx7ba8). Хотел выложить код напрямую сюда, но часть кода не отображается.

Т. к. пока не знаю причины проблемы, то не исключаю, что дело не в программе, потому если у Вас всё работает - так и напишите. Также, если у Вас получиться выполнить замену, прошу Вас пояснить причину, по которой ранее не получалось.

---

**Обновление**

Выяснил, что если запросить `<xmp><?= $doc ?></xmp>`, то в выведенном HTML-коде изменения будут. Может быть phpQuery просто не влияет на исходный файл и нет другого пути, кроме как редактировать его стандартными php-средствами (`fopen`, `fwrite`, регулярные выражения)?

Comment: Похоже, стало ясно... Так значит 'PHPQuery' не внедряется в исходный файл и воздействует только на выводимый результат? Очень жаль, ведь мне нужно именно редактирование исходного файла через админ-панель.

Comment: А сохранения файла то выполняется? Оно сам по себе не запишется обратно.

Comment: `file_put_contents("../".$filename, $doc->appendTo('<div></div>')->html())`

Comment: Проще `DOMDocument` заюзать.

Comment: Я видел только изменение значений, а сохранение вы делаете? Где запись изменений?

Answer (score 1):

Попробуйте

```
$title = $document->find('title');
$title->text("content");
```

почитайте еще как использовать pq http://max22.ru/php-solutions/php-query/

Comment: Нет, бесполезно... Замены заголовка в файле не происходит. Добавил в вопрос исходники. Может причина в чем-то другом...

Comment: `$title->html("content"); ` ?