# PHP: Замена содержимого тэга в файле без удаления табуляции

Tags: php, html

Рассмотрим пример с [xnotes](http://xnotes.ru/notes/php-kak-zamenit-tekst-v-fayle) :

```
$filename = 'file.txt';
$file = file_get_contents($filename);
$file = str_replace('foo', 'bar', $file);
file_put_contents($filename, $file);
```

Как сделать аналогичную замену, только:

- Заменять будем наперёд неизвестное содержимое какого-нибудь тэга, например `<title>`
- Удаления отсупов в исходном файле быть не должно

Я пробовал так:

```
$filename = 'file.php';
$file = file_get_contents($filename);
$title_pattern='#<title>.+?</title>#s';
$test= str_replace($title_pattern, "Новый заголовок", $file);
file_put_contents($file, $test);
```

и ещё так:

```
$title_pattern='#<title>.+?</title>#s';
preg_match($title_pattern, $file, $matches);
$test= str_replace($matches, "Новый заголовок", $file);
file_put_contents($fileadr, $test)
```

В идеале, нужно зайти в файл, который на данный момент не отображается в браузере заменить там только содержимое одного тега, а остальное, что там есть, вообще не трогать и даже не читать (оно нам просто не нужно). Но я так подозреваю, что это за гранью возможностей PHP.

Ещё через PHPQuery [пытался](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/579448/phpquery-%D0%BD%D0%B5-%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B1%D0%BE%D1%82%D0%B0%D0%B5%D1%82-%D0%BC%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%BF%D1%83%D0%BB%D1%8F%D1%86%D0%B8%D1%8F-%D1%81-%D0%BE%D0%B1%D1%8A%D0%B5%D0%BA%D1%82%D0%B0%D0%BC%D0%B8-%D0%B2-%D1%84%D0%B0%D0%B9%D0%BB%D0%B5/579528#579528) сделать. В итоге удалось, но вся табуляция в исходном файле была поломана (задавал [вопрос](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/580414/phpquery-%D0%B2%D0%BE%D0%B7%D0%BC%D0%BE%D0%B6%D0%BD%D0%BE-%D0%BB%D0%B8-%D1%81%D0%BE%D1%85%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%82%D1%8C-%D0%B8%D1%81%D1%85%D0%BE%D0%B4%D0%BD%D1%83%D1%8E-%D1%82%D0%B0%D0%B1%D1%83%D0%BB%D1%8F%D1%86%D0%B8%D1%8E-%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B8-%D0%B8%D1%81%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%BB%D1%8C%D0%B7%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B8-newdocument) на эту тему, пока без ответа).

Comment: Если длина вырезаемой части строки не будет совпадать с заменяющей "даже не читать" не получится. Нужно ведь будет передвинуть весь текст после места замены на разницу длин

Comment: Да, необходимо заменять содержимое на что-то еще, равное по длине символов тому что там уже есть. НО это так если есть табуляция на этой же строке, если на других - то это не повлияет, если у вас есть переносы строк, разделяющие между собой табуляции. 
А вообще, зачем делать табуляцию посредством текста? Не проще её реализовать через стили?

Comment: Я говорю не о табуляции в отображаемом в браузере тексте, а о табуляции в HTML-коде. Зачем она нужна, Вы знаете, потому удаление табуляции затруднит чтение кода.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Вот так:

```
$filename = 'file.php';
$file = file_get_contents($filename);
$title_pattern='#<title>(.*)?</title>#s';
$test= preg_replace($title_pattern, "<title>Новый заголовок</title>", $file);
file_put_contents($filename, $test);
```

Comment: Отлично, всё работает! Спасибо Вам за ответ!